# How do I use Node.js to send an email every 10 seconds?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I'm not sure what's the best way to add a delay of 10 seconds.

setTimeouts don't work, I'm not sure...

In python, I'm used to doing "time.sleep"

I'm not asking for how to send an email. I'm asking how to execute a command every 10 seconds.

Comment: How about setInterval()?

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html for all types and well setInterval to make continious calls. Dont use setTimeout.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`setTimeout` will work but you have to recreate the timeout at the end of each function call.

You'd do that like this.

```
function sendEmail() {
  email.send(to, headers, body);
  setTimeout(sendEmail, 10*1000);
}
setTimeout(sendEmail, 10*1000);
```

What you probably want is `setInterval`.

```
function sendEmail() {
   email.send(to, headers, body);
}
setInterval(sendEmail, 10*1000);
```