# Integrating firebase realtime database with PHP and Hybris

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a question regarding integrating firebase realtime database in PHP,

What I'm trying to do is synching data between multiple systems. If one application change the data it should reflect in other systems. One application is in Hybris and the other applications are PHP web applications.

Is it possible to connect these applications with firebase? so that it will automatically update when we change data in any of these systems.

I don't need to synch all the data between systems but some configurations which used by multiple systems.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

it all depends on what kind of data you want to transfer. Hybris is a complex system with a huge database. You can't transfer all.

In your case, i image that when something is changed, you have to run some custom logic to save it in Firebase, then an event is automatically  triggered on the other system and update the database. If this was your idea, i would recommend writing a custom protocol to directly connect to your other system. Using Sockets is a good idea for that. You don't need a 3th party DB for that.

The other possible solution is to use Firebase as a common DB for both systems. But having the idea that Hybris is really complex, i don't think you can store proper data in a NoSQL database. It all depends on what exactly you want to store.

If you want to sync Product Description and Price (for example) you may use Firebase for that. If you want to sync the whole product with categories, features, carts, orders etc. i would recommend creating a custom sync between your systems.

Comment: I only need to synch some configuration data it is not huge.

Comment: If this is the case, i think a simple app/script (NodeJs, Python, bash, shellscript )  will do the trick.

Comment: @ Hristo Staykov - how I do that with node application?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response. You can setup a cron or a windows task to run every X seconds to start your nodejs app which reads your files and updates firebase (or run the app nonstop and read the files using a timeout or something) On the other side, you will have a similar app, which updates on firebase entry/update and writes the data to a file. Here are some basic links, which will get you started [link](http://javabeat.net/nodejs-read-write-file/) [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978674/how-do-i-use-node-js-to-send-an-email-every-10-seconds

Comment: @ Hristo Staykov - by configuration data I mean some values in Hybris database. like publish status, I want synch that information across different applications. I though of implementing it using firebase.